# fetch domain name from url

Tags: java, regex

I have an example url:

```
www.google.com
```

I would like to fetch only "com" from this url but I completely don't know how to do this :(

Maybe somebody was struggling with this problem and found a solution?

We have to keep it in mind that example can be more advance for example

```
www.mydomain.com.pl
```

and from this we have to fetch "com.pl"
Maybe there is a library who can deal with it very easily...

Each

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Have you researched the problem before asking here? Questions tend to draw more and better answers when the poster demonstrates some effort on their own part to solve the problem first.

Comment: Thanks...
I was thinking to create something like a dictionary with those suffixes but it would be very time consuming though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html)

```
URI uri = URI.create("htp://www.mydomain.com.pl");

InternetDomainName domainName = InternetDomainName.from(uri.getHost());

System.out.println(domainName.publicSuffix()); //com.pl
```

You cannot do this correctly without referencing the [Public Suffix List](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Public_Suffix_List) (which Guava does)

Comment: Nice one. Too bad it will fail for `http://www.oswiata.abc.com.pl` (lets hope  OP doesn't need it).

Comment: It fails because it throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid domain name: 'http://www.oswiata.abc.com.pl'` (but it may be caused by fact that I didn't use newest guava version, will update and see if it helps, UPDATE: nope, still doesn't work for guava 18).

Comment: thanks that's a nice answer....but can we do this withouth any external libaries?

Comment: Ya, rewrite the InternetDomainName class yourself! :)

Comment: @Michal If you know a lot about your data coming in you can write simple regex to strip the last part off. For example, match everything after the second dot in `www.mydomain.com.pl`. If you have to be very flexible, you need to use a third party tool or re-do a lot of the work those tools already do for you.

Comment: So I have a two options:
- use guava 
- if I dont want to use guava I have to download the list of all public suffixes and do it by myself :) 
thanks for answers and help

Comment: @Neil McGuigan, This works great for me. My problem is to keep this in sync with the latest public suffix list. Is there a great way to achieve the dynamic look up of the latest public suffix list?

Comment: @kamaljoshi Google updates guava w the updated public suffix list, so if you keep guava up to date you'll be reasonably set. Otherwise you'd want to recompile guava on each psl update

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan I am looking at the source code. Can you show which class or maven task is responsible for creating the auto generated PublicSuffixPatterns.java?  https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/thirdparty/publicsuffix/PublicSuffixPatterns.java